# On Riesz decomposition of Volterra operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

Let $T:L^2((0,1)) \to L^2((0,1))$ be the Volterra operator defined by
$$ Tf(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt.$$
Given any $\lambda\neq 0$ it is well known that there exists some positive integer $n=n(\lambda)$ such that $\textrm{Ker} (T-\lambda)^n=\textrm{Ker} (T-\lambda)^{n+1}$ and also that $\textrm{Ran} (T-\lambda)^n=\textrm{Ran} (T-\lambda)^{n+1}$ and finally that
$$L^2((0,1))=\textrm{Ker} (T-\lambda)^n \oplus \textrm{Ran} (T-\lambda)^n.$$

Now my question is whether these subspaces and the integer $n$ can be explicitly calculated in the case of the Volterra operator.

Comment: I am a bit puzzled by this question. $T$ has no point spectrum away from $0$, so Isn't the kernel of $(T-\lambda)^n$ always just the zero function?

Comment: I agree with @YonahBorns-Weil's comment, and I'd add that even the entire spectrum of $T$ consists of $0$ only.

Comment: In other words, $n=1$ works, since $\lambda\notin\sigma(T)$, so $R(T-\lambda)=L^2$, $N(T-\lambda)=0$.

Comment: In fairness, the Volterra operator can be unsettling at first, because it's very easy to implicitly assume that every compact operator has eigenvalues (in particular, that's true for self-adjoint operators and for finite-rank operators, for different reasons.)